# Armenian Alphabet Does Not Display on Some Pages

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I have recently had an issue with the Armenian alphabet not properly displaying on pages that do not use the default browser font. However, I have no idea what is causing this issue. Pages where the default font is used, such as Wikipedia, display the characters fine. Pages that have a set font, such as Google, display empty squares.

[image]

[image]

It should be noted that I have set all Armenian text to display in "Times LatArm," a font that is specifically for the Armenian alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

Disable DirectWrite.

Go to address bar and type chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write. There you will see the option to disable DirectWrite. It worked for me to display Armenian again.

Answer (score 0):

In Google-chrome, go to more tools =>Encoding => and choose "auto detect" or "Unicode (UTF-8)".
Any other browser, try setting the Encoding to Unicode-UTF8, and it should display correctly. 
Decades ago, a user needed to have the correct character set to display non-Latin scripts, but since Unicode, all languages can be displayed using Unicode.

Comment: I changed my encoding, but I still see empty squares.